# how to install plyer library in python? i have already installed plyer module , still am getting "no module error"

Tags: python

```
from os.path import dirname, join
import plyer

import time
import datetime
import threading
def notify_me():
    while True:
        plyer.notification.notify(title="COVID 19 cases of INDIA",message=get_corona_detail_of_india(),timeout=10,app_icon='icon.ico')
        time.sleep(30)
```

I am getting error 
: no module named plyer

Comment: try to install plyer module using : pip install plyer

Comment: I have already installed that , still am getting no module error

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what you want to import, for example:

```
from plyer import notification
```

Comment: `import plyer` is perfectly valid syntax. Your code does something different.

Answer (score 0):

check if the module is installed in your python environment. Have you tried `pip freeze`?